# Finding a subspace that is a deformation retract to a given space

Tags: algebraic-topology

$X=T^2\# T^2$,
$Y=$ an open disk removed from $T^2\# T^2$.

I want to find a subspace of $Y$ that is a deformation retract to $Y$ but not deformation retract to $X$.

The fundamental group of $Y$ is wedge of four circles? Can I use this fact to solve the problem? Or what different approach can I take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the fundamental polygon for $T^2 \# T^2$, you can see that if you remove an open disk you can deformation retract to the edges of the polygon, which gives you a wedge of $4$ circles. Thus $Y \simeq S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1$.

You can see that this is not a deformation retract of $X$ via fundamental groups: $\pi_1(S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1 \vee S^1)$ is the free group on $4$ generators, but $\pi_1(X)$ is not, so $X$ and the wedge of four circles are not homotopy equivalent and hence the wedge of four circles cannot be a deformation retract of $X$.

(Also, this is nitpicky and not very important here, but be careful with your wording: we say that one space is a deformation retract "of" another, or that one space deformation retracts "to" another, but we don't say that one space is a deformation retract to another space. Also, the fundamental group of $Y$ is the free group on 4 generators because it's the fundamental group of a wedge of four circles, but we don't say that "the fundamental group of $Y$ is a wedge of four circles.")